# Next and Previous button in swiper slider are not wokring

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

> I have posted the same question two days earlier but didn't get any
> answer so I'm posting again this question. May be I get lucky this time.
> My slider buttons are working fine with static data, but they don't
> work with the dynamic data. And unable to show the next or previous
> slide.

**My HTML Code**

```
<section class="browse-cat u-line section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">

                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide myreward-slider-item col-md-4" *ngFor="let reward of readableRewards; let i = index">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <div class="myreward-slider-img">
                                    <img
                                    src="{{reward?.Image}}"
                                    class=""
                                    alt="rewards">
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 text-left padding-20">
                                    <span class="text-light-black cat-name"><b>{{reward?.Title}}</b></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                         <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                         <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>

                        </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**My CCS Code**

```
.swiper-button-next:after,
.swiper-button-prev:after {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ff0018;
  background: #ff0018;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  right: 10px;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  left: 10px;
}

.swiper-button-disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the previous question you asked. Do you see any errors in your console and do you have this hosted on some site that we can check. Another thing to check would be whether the slide contains more than one item

Comment: Here is the link to my previous question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793878/next-and-previous-button-are-not-working-in-swiper

Comment: I didn't host it. But I can share the picture if that can be helpful ?

Comment: Try removing the styles for the button and check if they become visible. 

Open devtools and search the HTML using the button class names to check these buttons have been created.

If they exist, check width and height of the buttons. Also go through all computed CSS that are applied to these buttons

Comment: I've removed the CSS. Buttons are visible. The problem is that they are not performing their intended functionalities. Like buttons are not working when they clicked and respectively not showing previous or next slide.

Comment: Can you also share the code where you have initialized the swiper slider. Are you initializing swiper slider before you dynamically fetch and insert the child elements of the slider. If so, have you set the observer option in swiper configurations

Comment: I've not initialized it anywhere else. I just imported its packages in angular. And started using it. I've already shared my HTML code above.
It's working fine with static data. when I loop some dynamic data buttons just didn't work

Comment: Please share a link to the angular swiper package you are using. Is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper) the package you are using. If yes, you will have to set the observer config property to true as mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper#available-configuration-options-custom--global-configuration)

Comment: I've set the observer config property to 'true'. But buttons are still not working

Comment: You may also want to check if any of the other properties under Image and Observer section is applicable to your case. You can find the documentation [here](https://swiperjs.com/api/)

Comment: Ok I'll take a look. Thank you for your time and help